# Request.Form timesout with PDF file attached, but not other file types

Tags: c#, rest, post, multipartform-data, .net-6.0

I am having trouble uploading a pdf file.
When I attach the PDF to my request HttpRequest.Form will time out in the debugger watch window.  In code, the call to HttpRequest.Form never returns.
I don't have this problem when I upload a text file or a png image file.  I am seeing it with several PDF files.

I use this command to upload (I get the same behavior with postman and soapUI):

> curl -F File=@"testFile.pdf" http://localhost:7060/api/Document

When uploading the PNG, if I read the request body I get the value below.

> --------------------------228c3d46f4f7cdfe Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="see.png" Content-Type: image/png
>
> �PNG

When uploading the pdf I don't have the metadata.  The request.Body is just symbols indicating the binary.  I do  see that request.ContentType is:

> multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5b3f1e35a9ac0617

What am I missing?

Comment: What does Wireshark show? Did the request actually fully send? (is the `.pdf` file locked locally and so can't be sent entirely?) - also I noticed the PDF file's `Content-Type` is missing entirely, which is strange - every browser today knows the PDF content-type. What happens in other browsers or in tools like Postman or wget/curl?

Comment: I am not doing it with a broswer.  I am only using curl, postman, and soapUI, and getting the same results.  On the server the request content type shows as multipart/form-data.

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is the Content-Type of the request body, however I'm referring to the content-type of the PDF **part** of the multipart request. Each "part" has its own `Content-Type` in its multipart header, along with (optionally) `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: I set the contenct-type of PDF part in postman and I am getting the same results.